# iptables blocking access to a service (Cloud9)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, iptables

I want to create a Cloud9 server using a raspberry pi. I download the repository and it ran just fine in the port 8181 as it shows below. I could even access the panel from the Raspberry using Chromium[image: Cloud9 server running]

But when I tried to connect to it from another computer in the same network, it instantly showed me this screen with the error "connection refused", so I assumed it was something to do with the firewall.:
[image: Error]

I followed some tutorials to allow traffic through port 8181 but nothing worked. Later, I tried using ufw, and configured it like this: 
[image: UFW configuration]

And running the command iptables -L I got: [image: IPTables -L]

And I still got the same error when trying to access.
Does anyone knows how I can properly allow traffic through the port 8181 or completely disable firewall from my raspberry pi?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the firewall, your server is bound to the loopback address, `127.0.0.1`.

If you want to connect from other hosts, you must change the address to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: And where is the problem with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I tried that, got the same connection refused error.